how to prevent pandoc from removing leading underscore from sections in markdown?
Pandoc when processing markdown sections removes the leading _ when producing html with id tag:
$ pandoc -f markdown - <<<'Go to [_section](#_section)'$'\n\n''### _section'
<p>Go to <a href="#_section">_section</a></p>
<h3 id="section">_section</h3>

The id="section' is wrong, it should id="_section". This breaks the links, href="#_section" navigates to _section not to section.
What can I do to fix?

You'll see that ### _section is converted to <h3 id="section">_section</h3> due to how pandoc normalizes ids (see the manual). What you can do instead is:
### \_section {#_section}

which is converted to:
<h3 id="_section">_section</h3>

(tested in pandoc 3.5)
